# Ubuntu 13.04 hangs on reboot (shutdown works fine)

Tags: 13.04, reboot

I have Ubuntu 13.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad SL510. Since upgrading to 13.04, the computer hangs on the Ubuntu loading screen (the changing white and orange dots) when rebooting. Turning on and off however works fine.

Comment: You should try this again, then copy syslog and dmesg.0 (dmesg is the log from the current session, dmesg.0 from the one before) from /var/log to wherever you want and inspect them. Please add the last lines the system hangs on to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue on 5 different 13.04 systems they all get stuck in run level 1 if you use `sudo reboot now`, this is a serious issue, I don't want to have to physically reboot all remote servers I manage.

The solution is to use `sudo shutdown -r now` which works and reboots.